# How can I color all the first bar by the same color, and the second color by another in subplot?

Tags: matlab, plot, progress-bar

I want to create a subplot, I have 6 figures, in each figure I have 3 bars, I want to color all the first bars by the same color and add a legend. please help me, this is the code:

```
x1=[1;2;3]
y1 = [91,25,3];
y2 = [71,22,13];
y3 = [81,22,33];
y4 = [71,12,63];
y5 = [61,42,23];
y6 = [51,21,23];
figure;
subplot(3,2,1);
b1=bar(x1,y1);
ylabel('Cost per Byte (%)');
ylim([0 max(y1)+10]);
title('Aaa');
subplot(3,2,2);
b2=bar(x1,y2);
ylabel('Security (%)');
ylim([0 max(y2)+10]);
title('Second plot');
subplot(3,2,3);
b3=bar(x1,y3);
ylabel('Data rate (kbps)');
ylim([0 max(y3)+10]);
title('Third plot');
subplot(3,2,4);
b4=bar(x1,y4);
ylabel('Delay (ms)');
ylim([0 max(y4)+10]);
title('Fourth plot');
subplot(3,2,5);
b5=bar(x1,y5);
ylabel('Jitter (ms)');
ylim([0 max(y5)+10]);
title('Fifth plot');
subplot(3,2,6);
b6=bar(x1,y6);
ylabel('Loss ratio 10^6 (ms)');
ylim([0 max(y6)+10]);
title('Sixth plot');
legend('peaks');
set(b1,'FaceColor','red');
```

I want colorate all the first bars by a color and add a legend like the picture :
[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to access the Bar's CData per subplots as shown here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html

Example:
b1.CData(2,:) = [0.5 0 0.5]; % With the RGB code.